# Sequence of continuous functions converges to bounded measurable function a.e continuous.

Tags: measure-theory, simple-functions

Let $(\mathbb{R},B,\mu)$ be measure space where $B$ is Borel sigma algebra, and $\mu$ is probability measure.

Let $g :(\mathbb{R},B,\mu) \to (\mathbb{R},B)$ be nonnegative bounded measurable function such that $g$ is almost everywhere ($\mu$) continuous.

Is there sequence of continous function $g_n$ such that $g_n(x) \to g(x)$ at continuity of $g$?

My try: 
1. there are sequence $g_n$ of simple-function converges to $g$ a.e $\mu$.

2. Since Borel measurable set is approximated by finite union of open intervals, simple function has form $\sum \chi _I$ where $i$ is open interval.
3. If simple function $g_n$ is discontinous, then I transform graph of $g_n$ so that $g_n$ is continuous.(BY linear function)

But I think $3$ is impossible.

Could you help me?

Comment: What's your definition of continuous a.e.?

Comment: $\mu$ is probability measure. g is continuous a.e $\mu$ means that there is borel set $B$ g is continuous at all points on$B$ and $\mu(B)$

Comment: So is 1 on rational and 0 on irrational continuous?

Comment: What's your mean?

Comment: The function you give is not continuous. But Is it related to my question? why?

Comment: Can you not have a sequence of continuous functions that converges to 1 on rational and 0 on irrationals? I can't remember.

Comment: @Jacky chong The function you said is discontinuous at all points. My assumption is $g$ is continuous almost everywhere.